# How to remove and add tabbar item in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, tabbar

How to remove checkout bar item when the cart is empty and show again if the cart is load, also remove the space when it 3 item

[[image: this is the 4 item]]

I tried this but it removes the item from the array

```
  if var tabs = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
            tabs.remove(at: indexToRemove)
            self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = tabs
        } else {
            print("There is something wrong with tabbar 
  controller")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Above you are removing the viewController from the `tabs` array, not the tabBarController's viewControllers array. (check the count of the two arrays to show this)

All you need to do is:

```
 self.tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at: indexToRemove)
```

This will remove the viewController from the tab bar.  As an aside, depending on how the viewController was created,  it may also de-initialise it so just be aware of that if you are planning to add it again later without reinitialising it.  Make sure you have a strong reference to it.  To add it back, just insert in back into the array.

Comment: how to add same bar item again here checkout item

Comment: As per my last paragraph, keep a reference to the viewController.  If you already have a stored property for it, use that, otherwise `.remove(at:)` returns the removed element so you can capture and use that. `let removedVC = tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at: indexToRemove)` and then `tabBarController.viewControllers?.insert(removedVC, at: indexToInsert')

Answer (score 0):

In my case view controllers were handled manually, so `tabBarController` was nil. So this is my answer for the question summary itself:

```
tabBar.items?.removeFirst()

tabBar.items?.insert(yourNewTab, at: 0)
```